# What kind of "stand" for photo taken from above? E.g., food photography

Tags: tripod, food-photography

I want to take photography of things laid on a table (fabric, drawing and painting mainly). So, basically, the lens just above it.
Are there "special stands" for this kind of photo?
So far, I saw 2 methods, both using tripod:

- one with an tilting column:
  [image: Tripod with column]
- one with a simple tripod, but a little bit tilted and secured with a string or something like that.

But does "table stand" or something like that exists? You know, something that works like an enlarger, but with a camera instead of the lens:
[image: Enlarger]

It seems like it would be simpler to have that kind of thing than a tripod.

Thanks!

EDIT: apparently this "technic" is called "overhead camera".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stands like that do exist. They're called [copy stands](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=copy%20stands&N=0&InitialSearch=yes&sts=ma&Top%20Nav-Search=) and as you might imagine they were designed to copy things, usually flat artwork.

There are other options. [Camera stands](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Camera-Stands/ci/415/N/4075788761) often have overhead arms, though they're bulky and expensive, though very stable.

Tripods do work well if you have a counterweight. They also make [jibs](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=jib&N=0&InitialSearch=yes&sts=ma&Top%20Nav-Search=) for tripods (usually larger tripods) that go even further.

And finally there's the [truly fancy](http://www.jlfisher.com/jibs_and_crossarms/jibs.html) stuff they use in hollywood.

You can rent some of the stuff – particularly the jibs – that are too expensive to buy. If you have a local TV or film equipment rental shop they'll have some of this stuff.

Or you can rig something up in another way – I've used a Bogen Magic Arm for overhead shots and Casey Neistat has built his own overhead shooting table out of scrap wood. But mostly I use tripods with counterweights.

Comment: Dang, those prices! This is the answer to my question, but I forgot to mention the price. I though something in the $100 range would be available, but clearly that's not the case :D.

Comment: Yea. That's why I use a tripod or a bogen magic arm unless I'm renting. Mattdm went over a few clamping options like the magic arm, which work great though can be a bit wobbly.

Answer (score 4):

The column of a tripod is often reversible, so you can straddle the subject and shoot downwards. Or you can build a gantry, though it's not really needed for today's lightweight cameras.  I sometimes see this sort of  arm.  What I MOSTLY see is just a normal tripod, used normally.  You can get pretty close to straight-down, maybe in conjunction with a slightly tilted table, without getting complicated.

[image]

Comment: One possible issue with the inverted column method is that it can make lighting a little more complicated, with the legs potentially throwing shadows around. I guess you could potentially turn the whole tripod into a light tent, though...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to copy stands, you might consider the [Manfrotto Super Clamp](https://www.manfrotto.us/super-clamp-w-stud) and some of its various accessories.

[image: clamp]

For example, there are various articulated arms with 2 or 3 sections, and in double or single depending on the weight you want to support.

[image: articulated arm]

Or, double-jointed ball head:

[image: double jounted]

These aren't cheap — $30 for one clamp, and the various camera mounting options will set you back another $60 to $200, depending on options, but it's all very sturdy. You'll get a better solution than something frighteningly rigged together with gaffer tape, and it's much more versatile than a dedicated copy-stand setup would be.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because that's what I exactly asked, without mentioning the price. However, I think I'll end with your solution: clamps and articulated arm. It seems more practical and less expensive.

Comment: With a superclamp, a spare head and a centre column from an old/spare tripod, you can do quite well, though you may need a counterweight

Answer (score 3):

You want a reproduction arm, sometimes called a sidearm or crossbar.

[image: repro arm]

Comment: Thanks. However it needs to be installed on a tripod, so it's not an ideal solution for me (in this case, I can just use the tilted column on my tripod). I didn't know this kind of arm existed though.

Comment: The knuckle in the middle of the repro arm pictured above has a 3/8 receiver with 1/4-20 adapter on the bottom. You can mount it on your tripod just like your camera.

Then you mount your camera on one of the ends. 

https://i.imgur.com/kkPTyqQ.jpg